# Kibana windows batch file - unused variables

Tags: batch-file, kibana

The following is the `Kibana.bat` file to start Kibana on Windows:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
for %%I in ("%SCRIPT_DIR%..") do set DIR=%%~dpfI
set NODE=%DIR%\node\node.exe
set SERVER=%DIR%\src\bin\kibana.js
set NODE_ENV="production"
set CONFIG_PATH=%DIR%\config\kibana.yml
TITLE Kibana Server 4.0.1
"%NODE%" "%SERVER%" %*
:finally
ENDLOCAL
```

The following line appears to be the one which actually runs Kibana:

```
"%NODE%" "%SERVER%" %*
```

When echoed, this gives:

```
"C:\kibana-4.0.1-windows\node\node.exe" "C:\kibana-4.0.1-windows\src\bin\kibana.js"
```

The other parameters such as `NODE_ENV` and `CONFIG_PATH` do not appear to be used (and the batch file will work if they are removed). Given that, what could be the purpose of these variables?

Thanks

Comment: They're probably environment variables needed by Kibana.

Comment: So SET variables are not just used within a batch file, but are also accessable in the environment? If the variables are used by the environment, why does Kibana still start when those variables are removed from the batch file?

Comment: Batch variables are local to the instance of CMD that is running. They can only be accessed by things that are started from within that CMD instance, and only while the instance is still open. As for why Kibana starts without them, I don't know; I don't use Kibana. I can only guess that Kibana doesn't need those variables during its startup sequence, but it might need them later.

Comment: The `%*` in a batch script refers to all the arguments supplied to the _current_ script (or a subroutine)

Comment: @user1052610, I recommend to not use variable name `DIR` as this is an internal command as well...

Answer (score 0):

`Kibana.js` refers to `NODE_ENV` but will use a default setting of `development` if it is not set:

i.e.

```
var env = (process.env.NODE_ENV) ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'development';
```

Looking in the repo on https://github.com/elastic/kibana CONFIG_PATH is also used in Kibana but has a fall back if it is not set.